# Which API or library should I use to get a JSON object

Tags: android, json

I want to pull a JSON object down from the internet. I've seen numerous examples for `HTTP Client` but I read from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) that

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

So should I be using `HttpURLConnection` because I found that some people are using a library called `Volley`.

Comment: If regarding to deprecation, actually, you can easily find that Volley still uses deprecated Apache library :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really not doing any heavy lifting in your application like downloading videos etc, `google android volley` is your best choice right now.

Volley is a networking library developed by Google and introduced during Google I/O 2013. It was developed because of the absence, in the Android SDK, of a networking class capable of working without interfering with the user experience.

**WHY VOLLEY?**

- Avoid `HttpUrlConnection` and `HttpClient`. These classes are really difficult to use and are not really without bugs.
- Avoid `AsyncTask`
- It provides cancellation APIs
- It is much faster
- It caches everything
- It has small metadata operations

Moreover if you have already used the `AsyncTask`, you will find `volley` really similar and even easier. `Volley` helps a lot to avoid the deadly `NullPointerException`.

Some time ago, the Google+ team did a series of performance tests on each of the different methods you can use to make network requests on Android. Volley got a score up to ten times better than the other alternatives when used in RESTful applications.

> It is not so good, however, when employed for streaming operations and large downloads.

Comment: This is the answer I was waiting for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must use [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). No doubt, you can use any library like **Volley**, **Retrofit** etc. But they are also using the same thing.

Documentation for [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Comment: It it worth using a library? I realized when I used Picasso Image Library that some things are just better done with libraries. Is that the case here?

Comment: Library are made for our ease. Picasso is the library for images which stores the images in cache, which doesn't download the image over and over again. So, if you want to use library, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used retrofit with GSON "As a parser" saved me a lot of time Volley is great too